# Offline SignalR Chat

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, signalr

I have an online chat room, which works fine. However I would like to be able to send messages to offline users. How can I modify the code below to implement this change?

I would like to change ConnectedUsers to AllUsers, but for offline users I don't have a ConnectionId.

ChatHub.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using catchme.bg.Data;
using catchme.bg.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace catchme.bg
{
    [Authorize]
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        private CatchmeContext _context { get; set; }

        public ChatHub(CatchmeContext context) 
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        #region Data Members

        static List<UserDetail> ConnectedUsers = new List<UserDetail>();
        static List<MessageDetail> CurrentMessage = new List<MessageDetail>();
        static List<PrivateMessageDetail> CurrentPrivateMessage = new List<PrivateMessageDetail>();

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            var userName = Context.User.Identity.Name;

            var id = Context.ConnectionId;


            if (ConnectedUsers.Count(x => x.ConnectionId == id) == 0)
            {
                ConnectedUsers.Add(new UserDetail {ConnectionId = id, UserName = userName});

                CurrentMessage.Clear();

                CurrentPrivateMessage.Clear();

                foreach (var user_name in ConnectedUsers.Select(u=>u.UserName).Distinct())
                {
                    CurrentMessage.AddRange(GetMessageDetailsForUser(user_name).Result);

                    CurrentPrivateMessage.AddRange(GetPrivateMessageDetailsForUsers(Context.User.Identity.Name, user_name).Result);
                }

                // send to caller
                await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("OnConnected", id, userName, ConnectedUsers, CurrentMessage, CurrentPrivateMessage);

                // send to all except caller client
                await Clients.AllExcept(id).SendAsync("NewUserConnected", id, userName, CurrentPrivateMessage);
            }
        }


        public async Task SendMessageToAll(string message)
        {
            var userName = Context.User.Identity.Name;
            // store last 100 messages in cache
            AddMessageinCache(userName, message);

            // Broad cast message
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("MessageReceived", userName, message);
        }

        public async Task SendPrivateMessage(string toUserId, string message)
        {

            string fromUserId = Context.ConnectionId;

            var toUser = ConnectedUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ConnectionId == toUserId);
            var fromUser = ConnectedUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ConnectionId == fromUserId);

            if (toUser != null && fromUser != null)
            {

                // send to 
                await Clients.Client(toUserId).SendAsync("SendPrivateMessage", fromUserId, fromUser.UserName, message);

                // send to caller user
                await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("SendPrivateMessage", toUserId, fromUser.UserName, message);

                AddPrivateMessageinCache(fromUser.UserName, toUser.UserName, message);

            }

        }

        public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception ex)
        {
            var item = ConnectedUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ConnectionId == Context.ConnectionId);
            if (item != null)
            {
                ConnectedUsers.Remove(item);

                var id = Context.ConnectionId;
                await Clients.All.SendAsync("UserDisconnected", id, item.UserName);

            }
        }


        #endregion

        #region public Messages

        private void AddMessageinCache(string userName, string message)
        {
            var publicMessage = new MessageDetail {UserName = userName, Message = message};
            CurrentMessage.Add(publicMessage);
            _context.MessageDetails.Add(publicMessage);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            if (CurrentMessage.Count > 100)
            {
                CurrentMessage.RemoveAt(0);
                _context.MessageDetails.Remove(CurrentMessage[0]);
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }


        }

        #endregion

        #region private Messages



        private void AddPrivateMessageinCache(string userFrom, string userTo, string message)
        {
            var privateMessage = new PrivateMessageDetail { UserNameFrom = userFrom, UserNameTo = userTo, Message = message };
            CurrentPrivateMessage.Add(privateMessage);
            _context.PrivateMessageDetails.Add(privateMessage);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            var singleUserPrivateMessages = CurrentPrivateMessage.Where(u => u.UserNameFrom == userFrom && u.UserNameTo == userTo).ToList();

            if (singleUserPrivateMessages.Count > 100)
            {
                CurrentPrivateMessage.Remove(singleUserPrivateMessages.First());
                _context.PrivateMessageDetails.Remove(singleUserPrivateMessages.First());
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }


        }

        #endregion

        public async Task<List<MessageDetail>> GetMessageDetailsForUser(string userName)
        {
            return await _context.MessageDetails.Where(u=>u.UserName==userName).ToListAsync();
        }

        public async Task<List<PrivateMessageDetail>> GetPrivateMessageDetailsForUsers(string userFrom, string userTo)
        {
            return await _context.PrivateMessageDetails.Where(u => u.UserNameFrom == userFrom && u.UserNameTo== userTo).ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@*<div>
        <form id="send-form" action="#">
            Send a message:
            <input type="text" id="message-textbox" disabled/>
            <button id="send-button" type="submit" disabled>Send</button>
        </form>
        <ul id="messages-list"></ul>
    </div>

    @section Scripts{
        <script src="~/lib/signalr/signalr.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/chat.js"></script>
    }*@

<link href="~/ChatStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/lib/jquery-ui/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

@section Scripts{
    @*<script src="~/lib/jquery-ui/ui/minified/core.js"></script>*@
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-ui/ui/minified/widget.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/mouse.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/draggable.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/resizable.js"></script>

    <script src="~/lib/signalr/signalr.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/chatjs.js"></script>

}

<div id="header">
    Chat Room
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />

<div id="divContainer">
    @*<div id="divLogin" class="login">
            <div>
                Your Name:<br />
                <input id="txtNickName" type="text" class="textBox" />
            </div>
            <div id="divButton">
                <input id="btnStartChat" type="button" class="submitButton" value="Start Chat" />
            </div>
        </div>*@

    <div id="divChat" class="chatRoom">
        <div class="title">
            Welcome to Chat Room [<span id='spanUser'></span>]

        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div id="divChatWindow" class="chatWindow">
            </div>
            <div id="divusers" class="users">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="messageBar">
            <input class="textbox" type="text" id="txtMessage" />
            <input id="btnSendMsg" type="button" value="Send" class="submitButton" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <input id="hdId" type="hidden" />
    <input id="hdUserName" type="hidden" />
</div>
```

chatjs.js

```
        $(function () {

            setScreen(false);

            var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                .withUrl("/hubs/chat")
                .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
                .build();



            connection.start().catch(err => console.error(err.toString())).then(function () {
                registerClientMethods(connection);
                registerEvents(connection);
            });

        });

        function setScreen(isLogin) {

            if (!isLogin) {

                $("#divChat").hide();
                //$("#divLogin").show();
            } else {

                $("#divChat").show();
                //$("#divLogin").hide();
            }

        }

        function AddUser(connection, id, name, privateMessages) {

            var userId = $('#hdId').val();

            var code = "";

            if (userId == id) {

                code = $('<div class="loginUser">' + name + "</div>");

            } else {

                code = $('<a id="' + id + '" class="user" >' + name + '<a>');

                $(code).dblclick(function () {

                    var id = $(this).attr('id');

                    if (userId != id)
                        OpenPrivateChatWindow(connection, id, name, privateMessages);

                });
            }

            $("#divusers").append(code);

        }

        function AddMessage(userName, message) {
            $('#divChatWindow').append('<div class="message"><span class="userName">' +
                userName +
                '</span>: ' +
                message +
                '</div>');

            var height = $('#divChatWindow')[0].scrollHeight;
            $('#divChatWindow').scrollTop(height);
}

        function registerEvents(connection) {

            $("#btnStartChat").click(function () {

                var name = $("#txtNickName").val();
                if (name.length > 0) {
                    connection.server.connect(name);
                } else {
                    alert("Please enter name");
                }

            });


            $('#btnSendMsg').click(function () {

                var msg = $("#txtMessage").val();
                if (msg.length > 0) {

                    //var userName = $('#hdUserName').val();
                    connection.send("SendMessageToAll", msg);
                    $("#txtMessage").val('');
                }
            });


            $("#txtNickName").keypress(function (e) {
                if (e.which == 13) {
                    $("#btnStartChat").click();
                }
            });

            $("#txtMessage").keypress(function (e) {
                if (e.which == 13) {
                    $('#btnSendMsg').click();
                }
            });


        }

        function registerClientMethods(connection) {

            // Calls when user successfully logged in
            connection.on("OnConnected",
                function (id, userName, allUsers, messages, privateMessages) {

                    setScreen(true);

                    $('#hdId').val(id);
                    $('#hdUserName').val(userName);
                    $('#spanUser').html(userName);

                    // Add All Users
                    for (i = 0; i < allUsers.length; i++) {

                        AddUser(connection, allUsers[i].connectionId, allUsers[i].userName, privateMessages);
                    }

                    // Add Existing Public Messages
                    for (i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {

                        AddMessage(messages[i].userName, messages[i].message);
                    }

                    // Add Existing Private Messages
                    for (i = 0; i < privateMessages.length; i++) {

                        AddMessage(privateMessages[i].userName, messages[i].message);
                    }



                });

            // On New User Connected
            connection.on("NewUserConnected",
                function (id, name, privateMesssages) {
                    AddUser(connection, id, name, privateMesssages);
                });



            // On User Disconnected
            connection.on("UserDisconnected",
                function (id, userName) {

                    $('#' + id).remove();

                    var ctrId = 'private_' + id;
                    $('#' + ctrId).remove();


                    var disc = $('<div class="disconnect">"' + userName + '" logged off.</div>');

                    $(disc).hide();
                    $('#divusers').prepend(disc);
                    $(disc).fadeIn(200).delay(2000).fadeOut(200);

                });

            connection.on("MessageReceived",
                function (userName, message) {

                    AddMessage(userName, message);

                });

            connection.on("SendPrivateMessage",
                function (windowId, fromUserName, message) {

                    var ctrId = 'private_' + windowId;


                    if ($('#' + ctrId).length == 0) {

                        createPrivateChatWindow(connection, windowId, ctrId, fromUserName);

                    }

                    $('#' + ctrId).find('#divMessage').append('<div class="message"><span class="userName">' +
                        fromUserName +
                        '</span>: ' +
                        message +
                        '</div>');

                    // set scrollbar
                    var height = $('#' + ctrId).find('#divMessage')[0].scrollHeight;
                    $('#' + ctrId).find('#divMessage').scrollTop(height);

                });

        }

        function OpenPrivateChatWindow(connection, id, userName, privateMessages) {

            var ctrId = 'private_' + id;

            if ($('#' + ctrId).length > 0) return;

            createPrivateChatWindow(connection, id, ctrId, userName);

            //Add Private Messages
            for (i = 0; i < privateMessages.length; i++) {

                $('#' + ctrId).find('#divMessage').append('<div class="message"><span class="userName">' +
                    privateMessages[i].userNameFrom +
                    '</span>: ' +
                    privateMessages[i].message +
                    '</div>');
            }

            // set scrollbar
            var height = $('#' + ctrId).find('#divMessage')[0].scrollHeight;
            $('#' + ctrId).find('#divMessage').scrollTop(height);

        }

        function createPrivateChatWindow(connection, userId, ctrId, userName) {

            var div = '<div id="' +
                ctrId +
                '" class="ui-widget-content draggable" rel="0">' +
                '<div class="header">' +
                '<div  style="float:right;">' +
                '<img id="imgDelete"  style="cursor:pointer;" src="/images/delete.png"/>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<span class="selText" rel="0">' +
                userName +
                '</span>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div id="divMessage" class="messageArea">' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="buttonBar">' +
                '<input id="txtPrivateMessage" class="msgText" type="text"   />' +
                '<input id="btnSendMessage" class="submitButton button" type="button" value="Send"   />' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>';

            var $div = $(div);

            // DELETE BUTTON IMAGE
            $div.find('#imgDelete').click(function () {
                $('#' + ctrId).remove();
            });

            // Send Button event
            $div.find("#btnSendMessage").click(function () {

                $textBox = $div.find("#txtPrivateMessage");
                var msg = $textBox.val();
                if (msg.length > 0) {

                    connection.send("SendPrivateMessage", userId, msg);
                    $textBox.val('');
                }
            });

            // Text Box event
            $div.find("#txtPrivateMessage").keypress(function (e) {
                if (e.which === 13) {
                    $div.find("#btnSendMessage").click();
                }
            });



            AddDivToContainer($div);

        }

        function AddDivToContainer($div) {
            $('#divContainer').prepend($div);

            $div.draggable({
                handle: ".header",
                stop: function () {

                }
            });

            ////$div.resizable({
            ////    stop: function () {

            ////    }
            ////});

        }
```

Comment: you want to send message that user, who is disconnected, right?

Comment: yes, that's correct

Comment: disconnected word it self telling that now you can not interact with that user, so it is not possible to send message to disconnected user until user is not reconnected.

Comment: I would like to save the message in the database and when the user comes online to show all messages to him

Comment: then, first you have to track that user using login info, because every time user connect, it comes with new connectionId. so it is not possible to send when user online only based on connection id

Comment: yes, I understand. But I have a List of users - ConnectedUsers, where each user has a ConnectionId and a UserName. I can use the UserName from the login info, but what do I do with the ConnectionId?

Comment: UserName is coming from Database or it will also change everytime ?

Comment: yes, UserName is coming from the Database

Comment: ok so only login user can connect with signalR, right ?

Comment: yes, but I can load a list of users from the database and show them in the chat window

Comment: ok, i am updating answer, you ca follow steps for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Please follow below stpes.**

1. First In OnConnectedAsync(), take static list object and store user connectionId with 
   username.
2. you need to use OnDisconnectedAsync(). so whenever your any user get 
   offline, you will get call in this method and you can get connectionId in this method, find username from your list.
3. Now take one schema where you can manage, Pending to send message user List.  add 
   useraname who is getting offline.
4. Now, When any user is connecting, first check whether that username is exist in 
   PendingToSendMessageUserList schema.
5. If yes, then first send him all pending message and then delete username from that 
   schema.

Hope you will understand, you need to implement it technically.

Comment: One more question: how do I message users, who have never been to the Chat page, but have registration in the web app?

Comment: So when user login, at that time you can add user in to chat user list. So you do no need to wait for user to go on chat page. Let me knowbif you have any query.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So what do I do with the ConnectionId when the user logs in?

Comment: add it in your user list, which you are using for sending message

Comment: I meant that when the user logs in, there will be no ConnectionId until he goes to the Chat page.

Comment: so you can start your hub from login page, instead of chat page. if you want to differenciate user that whather user came from chat page, or from login page, you can pass extar params and save it to hub class so you can do whatever you want to do based on user is on which page